# pagemethods is undefined - i believe that everything should be ok

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, pagemethods

I am trying to use PageMethods to call a function from the server side, but I am getting an error that PageMethods is undefined.

Here is what I have put into the html

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"   
  EnablePageMethods="True">
```

and here is the function from the code behind.

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Function LoadChild(ByVal EntityID, ByVal EntityCat, ByVal lnType, ByVal FullExpand, ByVal lnEquip, ByVal lnTemplate) As String
```

and here is the call to the function using page methods.

```
PageMethods.LoadChild(lnEntityID, lnEntityCat, GLOBALEQUIPID, FullExpand, 0);
```

can anyone see why I would keep getting a PageMethods undefined error? Thank you.

edit - part of the issue may be because the function isnt shared, but when shared is put in, i get this error in about 15 places. - this is refering to the session I am using - here is a snippet of the session being used that is showing an error.

```
prm4.Value = Session.Item("user_id")
```

I am getting the word session underlined with the error message below - any suggestions on how to fix this? this could fix the whole issue all together.

Error   305 Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Comment: Have you verified that the ASP.NET Ajax scripts are being included on the page? Also, that your call occurs after their inclusion?

Comment: how can i check to make sure these are included? sorry, this is my first time using page methods, and I've taken the instructions from here  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180355/Calling-a-code-behind-function-from-JavaScript

Comment: Use Fiddler and a page inspection tool like FireBug for Firefox, F12 dev tools for IE, Inspect Page for Chrome, etc...

Comment: is there anyway to just check for this with visual studio? it may be something simple I am missing like an import or reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page method should be a static(C#)/shared(VB.NET) method. Otherwise it does not work.
Yes, you can not refer instance property in static method. To get `Session` object you could use `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am now able to make my functions shared and use the session. This works.